# Use python object retrieved with TMDB API

Tags: python, api, object, printing, themoviedb-api

How can i use some data retrieved with TMDB API?

This is the function:

```
class Movies(Core):
    def __init__(self, title="", limit=False):
        self.limit = limit
        self.update_configuration()
        title = self.escape(title)
        self.movies = self.getJSON(config['urls']['movie.search'] % (title,str(1)))
        pages = self.movies["total_pages"]
        if not self.limit:
            if int(pages) > 1:                  #
                for i in range(2,int(pages)+1): #  Thanks @tBuLi
                    self.movies["results"].extend(self.getJSON(config['urls']['movie.search'] % (title,str(i)))["results"])

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.movies["results"]:
            yield Movie(i["id"])

    def get_total_results(self):
        if self.limit:
            return len(self.movies["results"])
        return self.movies["total_results"]

    def iter_results(self):
        for i in self.movies["results"]:
            yield i
```

And the call:

```
def search_tmdb(title):
  tmdb.configure(TMDB_KEY)
  movie = tmdb.Movies(title,limit=True)
```

The question is, how can i see and use the results of the object movie?

I'm sorry for the maybe stupid question but I'm approaching now to python

Comment: could you post the json that is returned from `config['urls']['movie.search']`?

Comment: yes @dm03514 is this: `config['urls']['movie.search'] = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%%s&api_key=%(apikey)s&page=%%s" % (config)`

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can do something like:

```
movies = tmdb.Movies(title,limit=True)
#if you want to deal with Movie objects
for movieresult in movies:
    #do something with the Movie result (here I'm just printing it)
    print movieresult

#if you want to deal with raw result (not wrapped with a Movie object)
for result in movies.iter_results():
    #do something with the raw result
    print result
```

`tmdb.Movies(title, limit=True)` creates a `Movies` object. Since the `__iter__` method is defined you can use `for movie in moviesobject` to go through the results in the `Movies` object. You could also get a list of `Movie` objects by using `movielist = list(movies)`.